# SQL Statement Only extracts 1 Record when more are present

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a weird one here!  I have a database table that has publication times and every minute a code is run that looks to see if something is to be published.  I know for a fact there are 3 different records that have 09:00:00 AM as the time.

When I run the following code I only get one record:

```
SELECT * FROM AutoContentTimes WHERE FireTime = '09:00:00 AM'
```

What could be wrong, it is very simple.  FireTime is char(11)

Many thanks in advance,

neojakey

Comment: Did you try: like '%09:00:00 AM%'?

Comment: Do ***not*** store times (or dates) in character columns. Use a `time` column instead and you won't have such problems.

Comment: @DHN This don't offer more, Normaly it should returns many records as he regarded.

Comment: Well it would offer more results, if there are e.g. trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @DHN So we should ask him to ensure the format or the values of his fields again!

Comment: maybe its case sensitive and the other 2 have Am or am.
In that case try UPPER(FireTime) = UPPER('09:00:00 AM')

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? `time` won't be available if 2005 or earlier. @DHN - There can't be trailing spaces if the value is `char(11)` as `09:00:00 AM` is 11 characters. Might be a missing space in the middle though.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos Very good idea, so neojakey should approve that values are the same.

Comment: I tried to recreate your situation and it works fine here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3050/2

Comment: @sємsєм yeah basically if it something like that you have to double check everything. Comparing Strings can be tricky sometimes...
Thats why I have to agree that if you can avoid it using DateTime or TIme in this case DO it.

Comment: I have made the change to time(7) as the field type.. and it has resolved the problem.  Many thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have `set rowcount 1` set.

Try `set rowcount 0`

And, as commented, don't store times as `char`. Use the appropriate data type.

Comment: I have made the change to time(7) as the field type.. and it has resolved the problem. Many thanks for your input.